# In Eclipse, is there a way to open a file by typing its path and name?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

IDEs are wonderful for many things. But I dislike how they make me use a GUI for something I can do faster typing in a command line.  For example, opening a known specific file.  If I know the name of a file, from the command line I can just type the name of my editor and the filename.  With tab-completion I can accomplish this very quickly in a reliable amount of time.  No searching through output or moving my fingers off the keyboard.

Is there a way in Eclipse to open a known file simply by typing its path+filename?  Maybe through a plugin?

The "Open Resource" shortcut (ctrl-shift-R) is almost it, but it only lets you type the name of the file, not the path. If you have several files of the same name in different directories, you must again hunt with the mouse for what you want.

Comment: In that case you'll love the Ctrl+3 shortcut: it lets you type in the name of any perspective, view, or setting, and open it. Not really an answer to your question, but I thought you'd appreciate it :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, if you are using Helios (Eclipse 3.6) you can use paths; for details, see ["New features in Open Resource dialog" in that version's "New and Noteworthy" page](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6-201006080911/eclipse-news-part1.html#open-resource-paths).

Also, you can Tab to the list of results and use the arrows to pick the right one.

Comment: Still not as good as a bash shell because you can't tab-complete partial directory names, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's the general File>Open option which is meant for opening arbitrary, but I don't know what that does if you point it to a file inside your workspace. This opens your normal platform open dialog which you might be more comfortable using quickly.

I think Open Resource is the closest you're going to get. You shouldn't have more than a couple of files with the same name, I would think, plus you can use wildcards to open files quickly. Also, remember that files you open more recently appear higher up the list of matches so you may find that the file you want is at/near the top of the list already.

Comment: File > Open doesn't have a keyboard shortcut on the mac.  Also the idea that one "shouldn't have more than a couple files with the same name" assumes a programming style which is not universal.  Python for example assigns special meaning to the file named __init__.py in any directory.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Open File" dialog, if you just start typing or paste from clipboard by Ctrl+V, the desired file will be selected.

The dialog before typing something:

[image]

The dialog after pasting the file location:

[image]

I'm using Neon.3 Release (4.6.3).